# Tensor product and homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $M$ be an $A$-module, and $M^*$ be $\mathrm{Hom}_A(M,A)$. Let $f$ be the map from $M \otimes_A M^*$ to $\mathrm{Hom}_A(M,M)$, such that, for all $x=\sum_i a_i \otimes b_i \in M \otimes_A M^*$, $f(x)$ is the homomorphism $y \in M \mapsto \sum_ib_i(y)a_i \in M$.
Is it true that $f$ is always a monomorphism ?
If not, is there a necessary and sufficient condition on $M$ for $f$ to be a monomorphism ?

Comment: It is a classical result that the mentioned map is a bijection if and only if $M$ is finitely generated and projective (fgp), so being fgp is a sufficient condition. But I believe we can weaken it to the module $M$ being merely projective.

Comment: Yes, if $M$ is projective, $f$ is a monomorphism, but the reverse is not true. For example, if $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$, then $M^*=0$, so $M \otimes M^*=0$, so $f$ is injective, but $M$ is not a projective module.

Comment: I think it is injective and the image is all  endomorphisms M that factor through a finitely generated projective. I don't have time to check details but the inverse map should involve choosing a factorization through some $A^m$ and then use the components to build something in the tensor product.  One would need to show well defined

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Maybe I misunderstood your comment, but you are saying that $f$ is always injective? I doubt that.

Comment: Maybe one should ask M to be finitely presented to be safe

Comment: I also highly doubt that this is sufficient.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, maybe it isn't.  I'm used to finite dimensional algebras

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how I would start.

Let $S$ be the class of all pairs of $A$-modules $(M,N)$ such that the canonical map
$$M \otimes N^* \to \hom(N,M), ~ m \otimes \omega \mapsto (n \mapsto \omega(n) \cdot m)$$
is a monomorphism. Both sides are additive functors in both variables. It follows formally that $S$ is closed under finite direct sums (in both variables) as well as under direct summands (in both variables).

Clearly, $(A,N) \in S$ and $(M,A) \in S$. It follows that $(M,N) \in S$ whenever $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated and projective (in which case the map is actually an isomorphism).

We can also prove that $S$ is closed under infinite direct sums in the *first* variable: Let $I$ be any index set and $(M_i,N) \in S$ for $i \in I$, then $(\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i,N) \in S$: This is because the map
$$\textstyle (\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i) \otimes N \to \hom(N,\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i)$$ is mono iff the composition
$$\textstyle (\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i) \otimes N \to \hom(N,\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i) \hookrightarrow \hom(N,\prod_{i \in I} M_i)$$
is mono, which identifies with the mono
$$\textstyle \bigoplus_i (M_i \otimes N) \hookrightarrow \bigoplus_{i \in I} \hom(N,M_i) \hookrightarrow \prod_{i \in I} \hom(N,M_i).$$

In particular $(M,N) \in S$ whenever $M$ is a free module, and hence also when $M$ is a projective module. (This special case has been mentioned in the comments already, but I wanted to show a conceptual proof.)

Remark: $S$ is not closed under infinite direct sums in the second variable. In fact, it can happen that $M \otimes A^I \to M^I$ is not a mono, so that $(M,\bigoplus_{i \in I} A) \notin S$.

The next case would be to look at two cyclic modules, say
$$M = A/I,~N = A/J$$
for two ideals $I,J$. Then
$$M \otimes N^* \cong A/I \otimes \mathrm{Ann}(J) \cong \mathrm{Ann}(J)/(I \cdot \mathrm{Ann}(J))$$ and
$$\hom(N,M) \cong \{[a] \in A/I : aJ \subseteq I\} = (I:J)/I.$$
The canonical map then identifies with $[a] \mapsto [a]$. This is clearly not a monomorphism in general, even for $I=J$ in which case we just get the map $$\mathrm{Ann}(I) \to A/I,~a \mapsto [a]$$
with kernel $I \cap \mathrm{Ann}(I)$. This kernel can be non-trivial: take $A = k[X]/\langle X^2 \rangle$ and $I = \langle X \rangle$.

Comment: If M is flat and N is finitely presented you get an isomorphism

Comment: Hmm, I guess this one won't make it on the too good to be true list like I hoped :)

Comment: Just to note. For finitely generated modules over a Noetherian ring, Auslander and Bridger studied this map extensively and used the notion of the Auslander transpose to provide an explicit description of the kernel of this map. It can be described as $\operatorname{Tor}^A_2(\operatorname{Tr} N,M)$. See "Stable Module Theory" by Auslander-Bridger for this and many related results.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg: thanks for the answer.

Comment: @metalspringpro: thanks. What is $\mathrm{Tr} ~N$ ?

Comment: @marco2013 $\operatorname{Tr} N$ denotes the Auslander transpose of $N$. It can be defined by taking a projective presentation $P_1 \xrightarrow{B} P_0 \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$ and setting $\operatorname{Tr} N:=\operatorname{coker} \operatorname{Hom}_A(B,A)$. It is only unique up to stable equivalence, but this is not an issue for its typical applications.

Comment: @metalspringpro: thanks for the answer.